# Show that $d^4k$ is Lorentz invariant

Tags: physics, problem-solving, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

> Show that $d^4k$ is Lorentz Invariant

2. Relevant equations

Under a lorentz transformation the vector $k^u$ transforms as $k'^u=\Lambda^u_v k^v$
where $\Lambda^u_v$ satisfies $\eta_{uv}\Lambda^{u}_{p}\Lambda^v_{o}=\eta_{po}$ , $\eta_{uv}$ (2) the Minkowski metric, invariant.

3. The attempt at a solution

I think my main issue lies in what $d^4k$ is and writing this in terms of $d^4k$
Once I am able to write $d^4k$ in  index notation I might be ok.

For example to show $ds^2=dx^udx_u$ is invariant is pretty simple given the above identities and my initial step would be to write it as $ds^2=\eta_{uv}dx^udx^v$ in order to make use (2).

I believe $d^4k=dk_1 dk_2 dk_3 dk_4$?

For example given a vector $V^u = (V^0,V^1,V^2,V^3)$ I don't know how I would express $V^0V^1V^2V^3$ as some sort of index expression of $V^u$ (and probably I'm guessing the Minkowski metric?). I would like to do this for $d^4k$.
Is this the first step required and how do I go about it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47556/lorentz-invariance-of-the-integration-measure

Comment: I need to use (2) , or I would get no marks..

Comment: It's the same answer @yourlazyphysicist. What does $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ do here? What does $M$ do in [the other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47557/157014)?